# Is there a WPF Control that lets you connect to a SQLSERVER database?

Tags: .net, sql-server, wpf, wpf-controls

quick question:

i was just wondering if there is a (freeware/open source) control for WPF that lets the user input the connection parameters to connect to a sqlserver DB and returns builds the  SqlConnectionString ready for use, before I write one myself. It's not that hard a task, but no sense in reinventing the wheel ;)

Just to be clear, I'm looking for something like this, which is taken from Microsoft's own SQL server management studio:

[image: Connection Dialog]

Comment: No offence but do you seriously belive in existance of such control?:) You can create one in 10min. time, using SqlConnection as a model.

Comment: Yeah, in fact that's what I did while waiting for the answer :P But the one in QL server management studio has some nice advanced options. And while those can be quite easily implemented as well with a bit of time, why waste an hour if there is something already available and well tested?

Comment: this sounds like a great opportunity for a CodePlex project!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing when I ran across Microsoft's [Data Connection Dialog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/DataConnectionDialog/) on NuGet.

Comment: Thanks mate! The question was 3 years old so don't need the answer anymore obviously, but still good to know in case I ever need it again. ;)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help you . [WPF SQL Connection User Control](http://jake.ginnivan.net/wpf-sql-connection-user-control)

Comment: Thanks, tho I had already found that on Google and the download link is dead unfortunately. In the end I ended up building my own control anyway. Thx anyway.

Comment: Link is back up again.